# Album artwork from mp3

Tags: android

i managed to read album artwork from my mp3 file(on sdcard) but the picture is
 biger than activity. How can i downsize(compress) picture to 150x150 pixels?

Comment: you can use bitmap's createScaledBitmap().

Comment: Thank you, this solution best suit my needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "fitXY" to scale an ImageView:

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="150dp" 
           android:layout_height="150dp"
           android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

You can set the source of the ImageView programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code will do the trick ;)

```
public static Bitmap decodeFile(File f, boolean goodQuality){
        try {
            //Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=100;

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale=1;
            if(!goodQuality){
                while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    scale*=2;
            }
            //Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }
```